# Does MMS support sending HTML content?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

We are using SMS to send text messages to our client base but recently there has been request to send HTML content as well.

I know SMS only supports text messages and the only way I am aware of sending any type of html content via SMS is to provide a link in the message back to the HTML source.

This however is not ideally what they'd like to do and prefer to send the actual HTML content as opposed to a link.

So I'm thinking MMS would likely be the comparable route to go; however I've been unable to find any type of tutorial in C# flavor using the Twilio API (MMS).

To add, I am only "guessing" that MMS would be appropriate to send HTML content; to my knowledge MMS is generally used for support of sending photos and other types of binary content (not necessarily HTML content), especially since I haven't seen any docs that explicitly state HTML support.

Of course, I will inevitably have to communicate to the requester's of this feature that using MMS would have potential of not reaching some of their customers due that MMS isn't something that is neccessarily enabled by default on every mobile device along with the fact the level of simplicity will be removed from the equation over use of SMS.

So am I correct that MMS will support HTML content and that it is a comparable alternative to SMS links; and can anyone possibly point me in the right direction for acquiring an MMS tutorial for Twilio in C#?

Comment: As far as I am aware MMS does not support any HTML functionality. Links etc are dependant on the handset software parsing etc. You may be thinking about the very old WAP pages from the 90s. Also MMS is expensive in terms of characters sent - so it wouldn't be feasible to send whole webpages via MMS.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the response. I know I couldn't find anything explicitly stating MMS supported HTML but I couldn't find anything stating it didn't either so I felt this would be a somewhat valid question to ask. That said, I'll explore other alternatives using SMS. Also, if you'd like to present your response as an answer, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, We can't send HTML content in SMS/MMS.

In MMS, the content that's "attached" to a MMS is fairly limited to video, audio and vcard files.